# Jsoup .text method not found

Tags: java, android-studio, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website for data using jsoup so I can use it in an Android Studio project. When I try to use the .text method to get all the text of a document, it says "cannot resolve method" even though I think I imported all the right things. Is this a problem with my code or is it something else?

My Code:

```
Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect(url).get();
text = doc.text();
```

**Edit: Found error, org.w3c.dom.Document was imported when the correct import is org.jsoup.nodes.Document**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `org.jsoup.nodes.Document`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com").get();
        String text = doc.text();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Google We've detected you're using an older version of Chrome.Reinstall to stay secure × About Store We've detected you're using an older version of Chrome.Reinstall to stay secure × Gmail Images Sign in Remove Report inappropriate predictions × A privacy reminder from Google Remind me later Review now United KingdomPrivacyTermsSettingsSearch settingsAdvanced searchYour data in SearchHistorySearch helpSend feedbackAdvertisingBusiness How Search works
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are creating Document wrong. Here's how we do it:

```java
URL url = new URL(.../*link here*/);
Document document = Jsoup.parse(url, 4000 /*timeout*/);
document.text();
```